# Entities not showing up in google cloud platform Entities console

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am currently working on google app engine and using datastore to store my data. I am facing an issue in which the entities I am creating through my code is not appearing in the entity section of the console. However, While querying the data return the data but this data is not showing up in the console. Does anyone has any clue to this regard,

Thanks,

Comment: Make sure you are looking at the right project and namespace, if you use namespaces.

Comment: Actually I have created a project and using its client id and secret so I am assuming that the entities will be create under the project whose client id and secret I am using, am I right?

Comment: I don't know which API you are using, but usually you have to pass a project ID unless you are on App Engine, in which case you don't have to use any client ID/secret.

Comment: I have created a project in the google developer console and using the project's client id and secret. Is there any specific setting that I need to configure the datastore with??

Comment: Ok so let me tell you the whole scenario in short. I am developing a google app engine application in which I am using google login usin oAuth 2.0 and also using google drive API to fetch the list of files and need to persist it in the datastore. Can you now guide me regarding to this?

Comment: well you are right I am not using any client id/secret as I am on google app engine but still the entities are not appearing on the google cloud platform console.

Comment: Possible clue: try creating an entity in the console, and seeing if it shows up via a programmatic query. It might give a hint as to whether you're looking at the right project, or might trigger some sort of refresh in the console. Once you've done that add it to your question as it provides some hints as to what's going on.

Comment: I have created a new entity with a new kind but when I call the entity with its id it says entity not found exception. Can you please tell me in google app engine how the application detects the project, from the client_secrets.json file from the client id/secret ??

Comment: The code I am using to get the entity is as follows:

Key boardKey = KeyFactory.createKey("test", Long.parseLong("5629499534213120"));
  
  try {
   Entity messageBoard = datastore.get(boardKey);
   
   messageBoard.setProperty("test", "123456");
   
   datastore.put(messageBoard);
  } catch (Exception e1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue and was able to fix it by opening the developer tools in the Chrome browser and then "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" the page.

In my case it was a browser caching issue.